# Proper Use of an ifstream Object as a Member of a Class

Tags: c++, class, parsing, ifstream

I have made a parser class to take in a large file of text and do various things. As a member of this class I have an ifstream object delcared as `ifstream fin`. I have a function `void SetFile(char* filename)` that takes a c-string literal and is supposed to call `fin.open()` to connect the stream to the file, but for some reason the `fin.fail()` is returning true immediately after the `fin.open()` call. Here is my parser class, hopefully someone notices what I'm doing wrong! Thanks for your time.

Parser.h

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Heap.h"
#include "Word.h"

enum FILESTREAM_ERRORS{OPEN_ERROR};

class Parser
{
public:
    Parser();
    void SetFile(const char *filename);
    void LoadHeap();

//private:
    int word, line, paragraph;
    ifstream fin;
    Heap<Word> *wordheap;
    void LoadWord();
};

Parser::Parser()
{
    word = line = paragraph = 0;
}

void Parser::SetFile(const char* filename)
{
    fin.open(filename);
    if(fin.fail())
        throw OPEN_ERROR;
}

void Parser::LoadWord()
{
    QString wordstring;
    char c;
    fin.get(c);
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        char p = fin.peek();
        if (p == '\n')
        {
            fin.get(c);
            paragraph++;
        }
        line++;
        fin.get(c);
    }
    while (isblank(c))
        fin.get(c);
    while (!isblank(c))
        wordstring.append(c);
    word++;
    cout << qPrintable(wordstring) << endl;
}

#endif // PARSER_H
```

Comment: Tip: Use a class for you exception management (see <stdexcept> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/). I suggest std::runtime_error or a subclass.

Comment: What is the filename?  What did the debugger show?  How is `SetFile` called?  Please post a minimal compilable amount of code that recreates the issue, including expected and actual inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your file exists, that you can effectively read it.

Activate [`std::ios` exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) to get more information on the error.

One another possible cause of `fail` is that the `fstream` already has a file associated to it. Check it with `is_open` before attempting the open operation.

---

Update from Drew Dormann comment :

If you specify a relative path, i.e. a path that is not absolute (typically starting with a drive letter on Windows or a slash on *nix), you should consider the value of the *current working directory* (CWD). This value is often by default the directory of you executable, but some OS or IDE may change it, and of course your program can change it also.

So if you use a relative path, also check the CWD (you can get it with `getcwd` on *nix), or for testing purpose use an absolute path.

Comment: It's probably also worth reviewing what "working directory" means.  A common mistake is thinking that a relative file path should always be relative to the executable.

Comment: I had my file in the wrong part of the project directory. I thought it belonged in the same folder as the header files, but in fact it wanted it to be in the folder that contains the release/debug folders.